# Facebook link_stat click_count remains zero

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I've looked in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/) and the facebook documentation says **click_count** is **The number of times Facebook users have clicked a link to the page from a share or like**. I've been playing with API and the counter remains 0 no matter what. Is it a bug?

Comment: What are you doing with the API that you think should increment that counter? There may also be a delay in that table updating after you make the post and a user clicks it

Comment: I am just trying to figure out how many users have actually clicked the URL. It always remains 0 no matter how much you wait.

Comment: Something tells me that a 'link' object, and a post containing a link are different are are recorded separately ; have you claimed the domain whose links you're trying to track? there should be insights available in the normal insights APIs

Comment: So,what is the purpose of the click count parameter than? And is there a way to get the click count (as mentioned above) for a given url? Do you have to get the object id for the url first (the "link object"?)?

Comment: Any updates on this? I am having this difficulty too.